# Error double literal found in Scala while executing jar tf command

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-repl

I have recently started learning Scala. I am trying to execute the `tf jar` command on spark -shell prompt

```
jar tf C:/spark/lib/spark-examples-1.6.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar
```

And it's throwing **error**

> error: ';' expected but double literal found.

Could someone please help me in finding the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Spark shell is a slightly customized Scala repl, it's not *that kind* of "shell". It has no idea about the usual `bash`/`cmd`-specific commands, and it assumes that you input only valid Scala definitions and expressions that you want evaluated. `C:/spark/lib/spark-examples-1.6.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar` is not a valid Scala expression.

Note the exact position where it fails: it fails right after `1.6`. Everything before the `1.6.0` part can be interpreted as Scala expression `C.:/(spark)./(lib)./(spark).-(examples).-(1.6)`, but it then fails to parse `1.6.0`, and exits with an error message.

Comment: Thanks Andrey for response.I have renamed the jar file as sample and modified the command as -

Comment: @Sam The actual name of the jar-file doesn't matter. In Scala / Spark there is no object `jar`, and it has no method `tf`, therefore the expression `jar tf someFileName` is meaningless to the Scala repl. You will have to either exit the scala repl, or open another `cmd`/`bash`-shell and issue the `jar` command there.

Comment: Ohh..Okay..Thank you..:)